# Scala standard library: "Explicit instantiation to reduce class file size in subclasses"

Tags: scala, abstract-class, standard-library, traits

In the Scala standard library there are several occurrences of the pattern "Explicit instantiation to reduce class file size in subclasses". Here for instance in Iterator.scala:

```
/** Explicit instantiation of the `Iterator` trait to reduce class file size in subclasses. */
private[scala] abstract class AbstractIterator[+A] extends Iterator[A]
```

In the whole source file, the abstract class is used to construct anonymous classes instead of the trait itself. Clearly the comment already gives enough motivation why this is done. But what is non-trivial to me: Why does this trick reduce the file size at all and why is the size of subclasses affected and not Iterator itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you mixin or create an anonymous class from a trait, for all the concrete methods in the trait a stub method, that forwards the call to the concrete implementation is put into the class file. This will be done for **every** class, over and over again. If you instead create one abstract superclass, the methods will only be put there.

**edit**: changed post according to Régis Jean-Gilles comment.

Comment: Slight correction: the method bodies are **not** copied everytime you mix the trait. However, for each method of the trait you get a corresponding stub method that forwards to the actual implementation, and these stubs alone can take up a huge space (in terms of bytecode)

Comment: And I take it "subclasses" just refers to these anonymous classes and not to possible (external) subclasses of `Iterator` itself? The comment suggested that they are affected as well, which is probably not the case.

Comment: No, they will not be affected.

Comment: The distinction is more "class vs trait" than "anonymous or not". Mixing a trait incurs a bytecode penalty (because of the stubs), extending a class does not (because tis is standard JVM model and merely extending a class makes inherited methods accessible right away). So sub-classes of `Iterator` **do** incur this penalty, but sub-classes of `AbstractIterator` do not (the penalty is already *paid* by `AbstractIterator`).